# Loading Google Map Page Url inside <div>

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I am unable to load the google map page url inside div tag.

EX: $(".map_holder").load('https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/India/@21.1289956,82.7792201,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6');

I am getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://test.com:8887' is therefore not allowed access. " In crome browser.

In firefox nothing is happening.

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate with google maps you can either use their API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async
or embedd with an iframe (click the settings wheel and then "share and embedd" to get a ready made iframe.